# EWS: Appointment.Organizer sometimes empty

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Exchange was updated from RTM to CU6
Since this update I do get Appointments without an organizer.

We do use a global user to insert the appointments. Before the organizer would be the user that is impersionated. Now it is null.

I do use Bind and in some cases (I think with older appointments) I do have an organizer.

Is there anything you could think of? 
Is there any known error you know of?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add additionalProperties.Add(AppointmentSchema.Organizer);

It wasn't needet before. I do not know why now and why some of the Appointments have the Organizer filled whether the property is set or not and others don't, but since I set it it is allways filled again...